# back page and next page again with values still intact in edittext

Tags: android

Im wondering is there any method where i can use to have the same values display on the edittext after the application goes to previous page and back to the orignal page?

e.g in Page 1, the user pressed next page button and it goes to page 2, users key in some values in edittext. From page 2, i implemented onBackPressed(), therefore when the user goes back to page 1 the values on edittext is on where they are suppose to be.

here comes my question, when the user goes back to page 2 the values that will previously enter in the edittext are gone.

This the method i implemented on page 1 that enables users to goes to page 2

```
public void nextPage(View view) {
        variables vb = new variables();
        Intent intent_next = new Intent(this,
                Display_form_personal_details2.class);
        startActivity(intent_next);
```

This the method i implemented on page 2 that enables users to goes to page page 1

```
public void previousPage (View view){
        Intent intent_previous = new Intent (this, Display_form_personal_details.class);
        onBackPressed();

    }
```

Comment: Please learn the Android activity life cycle.  It is key to leaning how to write Android apps.  http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Answer (score 0):

use putExtras() method to get the value:

```
public void previousPage (View view){
    Intent intent_previous = new Intent (this, Display_form_personal_details.class);
    intent_previous.putExtra(<String name>, <String value>);
    onBackPressed();

}
```